# How to avoid regions overlapping in panels layout (or display suite) in Zircon Theme?

Tags: 7, theming

If a website window is scaled down by using mobile phones or reducing a browser window, some regions with fields in them (panels layout or display suite) start overlapping each other (they move onto each other).

Is there a way to avoid this effect? (tested on Zircon Theme Drupal 7)

Comment: Sorry, but as I mentioned before questions about CSS are off topic here. There's no Drupal-specific knowledge required, you should inspect the HTML and CSS on your page, find out what rule(s) are causing the problem, and override them as you would with any website. As an aside, Zircon lists a bunch of modules that it's compatible with, panels and display suite aren't listed amongst those. So it might be worth submitting a bug report or feature request to the module.

Comment: It is not an exact copy of a question. Maybe there is a solution where it is possible to use a programming code. I didn't mention css.